# TeXtalk interviews

Tags: discussion, community, blog

[TeXtalk http://tex.blogoverflow.com/files/2012/02/textalk2.png](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/files/2012/02/textalk2.png)

## Introduction

As part of the celebrations of our first birthday, we decided to interview great members of our community. Since we received very positive feedback from our beloved users, the **TeXtalk** became a regular event in our community blog.

Our interviews are also indexed in the [TUG Interview Corner](http://www.tug.org/interviews/).

## How does it work?

It's quite simple, actually. `:)` We have a [dedicated chatroom for interviewing our members](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1728). We schedule a time with the interviewee and everybody is invited to join the TeXtalk chatroom and submit questions. It's a very friendly conversation!

## I missed the interview! What do I do?

Do not despair, post-interview questions and remarks are welcome! `:)` We usually wait a couple of days, then "lock" the interview. We want to give our members the opportunity to read the chatroom transcript and add their own remarks or even submit questions to the interviewee. The format is working marvellously well so far. `:)`

We have a team of reviewers that put every bit of the interview in the correct order, so we can easily adjust the comments. `:)`

## How is the next interviewee chosen?

When we think it's time to have another interview (usually twice a month), we ask our interview committee to suggest names. This committee is composed of our [regular chatroom residents](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41). Once we reach a consensus, Paulo is in charge of making the official invitation. `:)`

## Available interviews

Legend:

- [image: Chatroom Bookmark] *Chatroom bookmark*
- [image: Blog post] *Blog post*

Currently, the following members have been interviewed:

- [image: Chatroom Bookmark] [image: Blog post] [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) (Nov 4 '11 at 18:33, 5 hours 5 minutes total)
- [image: Chatroom Bookmark] [image: Blog post] [lockstep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/510/lockstep) (Nov 6 '11 at 10:10, 3 hours 40 minutes total)
- [image: Chatroom Bookmark] [image: Blog post] [Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer) (Dec 9 '11 at 16:28, 1 hour 32 minutes total)
- [image: Chatroom Bookmark] [image: Blog post] [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner) (Jan 2 '12 at 17:48, 1 hour 43 minutes total)
- [image: Chatroom Bookmark] [image: Blog post] [Jake](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2552/jake) (Feb 1 '12 at 11:00, 3 days total)
- [image: Chatroom Bookmark] [image: Blog post] [Yiannis Lazarides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/963/yiannis-lazarides) (Feb 29 '12 at 12:34, 3 hours 10 minutes total)
- [image: Chatroom Bookmark] [image: Blog post] [Patrick Gundlach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/243/patrick-gundlach) (Mar 12 '12 at 16:29, 2 hours 33 minutes total)
- [image: Chatroom Bookmark] [image: Blog post] [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina) (Mar 27 '12 at 15:09, 2 hours 19 minutes total)
- [image: Chatroom Bookmark] [image: Blog post] [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) (Apr 12 '12 at 17:18, 3 hours 10 minutes total)
- [image: Chatroom Bookmark] [image: Blog post] [Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/andrew-stacey) (Jun 19 '12 at 18:11, 2 hours 22 minutes total)
- [image: Chatroom Bookmark] [image: Blog post] [PLK](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1657/plk) (Jul 30 '12 at 17:58, 23 hours 18 minutes total)
- [image: Chatroom Bookmark] [image: Blog post] [Aditya](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/323/aditya) (Aug 13 '12 at 14:01, 23 hours 47 minutes total)
- [image: Chatroom Bookmark] [image: Blog post] [Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright) (Sep 12 '12 at 13:58, 3 hours 45 minutes total)
- [image: Chatroom Bookmark] [image: Blog post] [Peter Grill](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4301/peter-grill) (Nov 4 '12 at 20:02, 2 hours 23 minutes total)
- [image: Chatroom Bookmark] [image: Blog post] [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388) (Dec 13 '12 at 13:03, 2 days total)
- [image: Chatroom Bookmark] [image: Blog post] [Marc van Dongen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10274) (Jan 22 '13 at 14:09, 35 days total)
- [image: Chatroom Bookmark] [image: Blog post] [Leo Liu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2674) (Mar 28 '13 at 13:35, 2 hours 55 minutes total)
- [image: Chatroom Bookmark] [image: Blog post] [Nicola Talbot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862) (May 18 '13 at 19:48, 19 hours 43 minutes total)
- [image: Chatroom Bookmark] [image: Blog post] [Khaled Hosny](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/729) (Jul 27 '13 at 18:37, 2 days total)
- [image: Chatroom Bookmark] [image: Blog post] [Paulo Cereda](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3094/paulo-cereda) (Nov 23 '14 at 14:59, 3 days total)
- [image: Chatroom Bookmark] [image: Blog post] [Mico Loretan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) (Feb 26 '16 at 13:01, 9 hours 10 minutes total)

## The lion

The lion used in the TeXtalk logo is (poorly) drawn by Paulo as an homage to the TeX community. From now on, we will have a thematic logo for each interview. For example, the lion's wardrobe might have something related to the interviewee. Can you spot the theme? `:)`

## The interview

In short, any TeX.SX member can be interviewed. The only requirement we ask is to provide the interviewee's (real) name for the indexing process in the TUG Interview Corner.

## I want to suggest an interviewee

Easy, go to [our TeX, LaTeX and Friends chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41) and write down your suggestions. `:)`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Our next interviewee:

## [image: user] To be announced