# How can one comment on a TeXtalk interview?

Tags: discussion, support, blog

unfortunately, i was not available while the interview with Aditya was happening, and i would like to comment on one point that he made:

"I think that there are a very few journal who will accept packages written with the
  breqn package, for example"

is there a comment mechanism that will allow me to add my two cents after the fact?  there's nothing obvious in the (current) link from [the interview intro page](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2545/textalk-interviews).

(by the way, this one, like all interviews so far, is interesting and well worth reading.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Barbara, feel free to add comments and/or questions to Aditya in the [interview chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1728/textalk-interviews). `:)`

We usually wait a couple of days to then "lock" the interview. We want to give the opportunity to our members to read the chatroom transcript and add their own remarks or even submitting questions to the interviewee. The format is working marvelously so far. `:)`

We have a team of reviewers (lockstep, Alan, Joseph, Andrew and others) that put every bit of the interview in the correct order, so we can easily adjust the comments. `:)`

I can also correct the chatroom bookmark to include all post-interview remarks. I'll update the intro page accordingly to mention this "feature". `:)`